# Ubuntu 14.04: mouse didn't load

Tags: 14.04, mouse

For a few months since I've upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, (almost) everything was working fine except for the occasional problems that I would get when logging in which were reported. But yesterday my mouse just decided not to load and now I have to try to navigate via keyboard and it's kind of a pain.
Any help will be appreciated.

-EDIT-
The computer model is Toshiba Satellite A135-S4467.
Here's the output when I do: cat /proc/bus/input/devices/

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=25b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=b
B: KEY=6420 0 30000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=11000003
```

I've checked if there were any driver updates for my touchpad device and there were none. All the repository sources in Software and Updates are on.
Checked it in live mode and still didn't work.
Checked the System Settings for Mouse/Touchpad -- everything is on.
Tried this: http://www.tuxtrix.com/2010/06/restarting-your-touchpadmouse-in-ubuntu.html
--still no luck.
I don't have dual boot on this laptop with Windows or anything, so can't really test to see if it's only on this operating system.

Comment: USB, Touchpad or Wireless mouse?

Comment: Touchpad mouse.

Comment: Have you checked if another mouse/pointing device works ?

Comment: Yep. I have a wireless mouse that works.

Answer (score 0):

Always try another mouse.  If the alternate mice don't work, then it's a driver issue.  If the alternate mice do work then it's a hardware issue.

For several years now I've been promoting Ubuntu to Windows users as a DIAGNOSTIC TOOL.  I suggest they boot their computer to an Ubuntu Live CD and that if it works right then their issues are with Windows, but if it doesn't work right then there are probably hardware issues.  Better than 9 out of 10 times, this litmus test works.

Answer (score 0):

### In case your Touchpad doesn't work at all (No response from the Touchpad)

This is generally a case of a kernel (**linux**) or **xorg** bug. Check by connecting an external mouse to see if that works or not.

If no, then you should file the bug against **HAL** and follow these steps:

- After reading [this](/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest) about how to enter VT and log evtest events, switch to a VT using Crtl+Alt+F2 and enter the following in your terminal:

  ```
  sudo evtest /dev/input/eventX > ~/evtest
  ```

  where the "X" in "eventX" is the event number found by typing in a terminal:

  ```
  cat /proc/bus/input/devices
  ```
- . Add identifier, Scroll, tap, drag, press buttons, and create various other possible events on the Touchpad. Then, press CTRL+C to exit and execute:

  ```
  cp /var/log/Xorg.0.log ~/Xorg.0.log
  ```
- . Press Crtl+Alt+F7 to switch back to X.
- . Add as separate attachments ~/evtest and Xorg.o.log.

If yes, execute at a terminal:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

One should see:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event8
B: EV=b
B: KEY=420 0 70000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=11000003
```

If you do not find something like this, then the bug is in the linux kernel. Please follow these steps:

File the bug against the **linux** package.

Provide the [general information](/DebuggingTouchpadDetection#generalinfo).

Enter the following commands in a terminal:

```
dmesg > ~/dmesg
cat /proc/bus/input/devices > ~/devices
```

Attach as separate attachments to your bug report ~/dmesg, ~/devices, and your /var/log/Xorg.0.log.

Comment: The links don't seem to work..

Comment: What was the output when you tried the above?
Try a USB mouse. It it works, then the problem might be a driver problem. Proprietary most likely.

Comment: I have compared the two and they are quite similar. Edit your question to include your Computer model. Have your tried using the touchpad in Live Mode? try upgrading your software In Addition, go to Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers tab. Check if there is any drivers for your touchpad device. Also, all the repository sources in Software and Updates. See image for help: http://i.stack.imgur.com/edKi0.png

Comment: Well, I've checked it in live mode and still doesn't work. I went to Software and Updates and I already have the exact same setup. There are no software updates for my touchpad, unfortunately. Is there still a solution for this problem besides using an external mouse?

Comment: Check the status of the touchpad switch (on/off) in System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad >Touchpad

Comment: Try [This solution](http://www.tuxtrix.com/2010/06/restarting-your-touchpadmouse-in-ubuntu.html) to restart your touchpad. Also, if you have windows, does it work in there?

Comment: Please update your question incorporating all the methods you have tried. For better question answers.

Comment: Still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

OPs solution:

> -SOLUTION-    Well I found where the problem lies. It turns out that I must have accidentally used the "function key + F9" which turns on/off
>   the Touchpad. Sorry for all the trouble, but thank you everyone for
>   your help.